# ssh key not authenticating on server for Github

Tags: git, ssh

I am facing issue for Git authentication via `ssh` key. I have created `ssh` key with the command `ssh-keygen -t rsa` on server in `home/projectname/.ssh` folder. Then added this key to Github account in `https://github.com/settings/ssh`.

When I am trying to pull the code below error occurs (pls check attached image)

`Permission denied (public key)`

Let me know what is the issue and how can I resolve it

Steps tried by me

- Tried with creating new public key
- Removed known_hosts file to recreate it
- Checked folder permissions and user details
- used `sudo` [image]

Comment: you should save your ssh key files in /home/.ssh and not in /home/projectname/.ssh

Comment: but its not allowing me to create `.ssh` folder in `home` folder. Permission denied error is occurring

Comment: I have posted a solution. You can try that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that github is looking for ssh keys in your /home/.ssh directory while you are saving your files in /home/projectname/.ssh

You have to add a config file in your /home/.ssh directory with the following content

```
Host github-project1
User git
HostName github.com
IdentityFile ~/projectname/.ssh/filename.key
```

Comment: but its not allowing me to create .ssh folder in home directory. Permission denied error occurring Though I am logged in with admin user.

Comment: You are saying that you are not able to create any folder in your home directory because of permission issues ?

Comment: Yes, Its not able to give permission to create folder there. I think because of `home/projectname` directory

Answer (score 0):

#### Create a SSH config file

```
Open a terminal window.
Edit the ~/.ssh/config file.
```

If you don't have a config file, create one.
Add an alias for each identity combination for example:

```
Host workid
HostName bitbucket.org
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/workid

Host personalid
HostName bitbucket.org
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/personalid
```

---

#### ***`How to add ssh key to github account?`***

- Login to github account
- Click on the rancher on the top right (Settings)
  [image: github account settigns]
- Click on the `SSH keys`
  [image: ssh key section]
- Click on the `Add ssh key`
  [image: Add ssh key]
- Paste your key and save

And you all set to go :-)

Answer (score 0):

Solution #1:

`ssh-add /home/projectname/.ssh/id_rsa
git pull origin master`

Solution #2 (for recent git versions)

`GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -i /home/projectname/.ssh/id_rsa' git pull origin master`

If solution #2 works, you can put `GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -i /home/projectname/.ssh/id_rsa'` to you `~/.profile` (or `~/.bash_profile`, whatever exists) and than it will be set upon login.